# Cordova camera support in iOS app conflicting with the ios location service

Tags: ios, cordova, core-location, cllocationmanager, hybrid-mobile-app

We have implemented a hybrid application. Our application is having the function like *Quick Receipts*, it does when user click on the quick receipts icon, camera get opens, user can take  the `img` and use it.

its working fine with android devices, but when same thing suppose to do with iOS devices, it's not working. The problem is in iOS is, camera get opens and when take the `img`, the control automatically moves to the dashboard without any actions. This happens when location services is ON.

> (iOS devices setting/privacy/location service enable).

if location service is disabled, then there is no issue with quick receipts function, it works fine. Please suggest how we can fix this issue without concern location services enable or disable.

Comment: You really need to provide some relevant source code to recreate the problem. It's going to be too hard otherwise to understand the issue you have.

Comment: @Ferrier for security reason we wont share the code publicly. but one thing in our application we are not using the location services and even its not requires to the app but still its conflicting .